# How can I destroy multi-session LTTng

Tags: session, destroy, lttng

I created an LTTng session:

```
# lttng create A
```

then unintentionally created another session:

```
# lttng create B
```

so i destroyed the session:

```
# lttng destroy
```

however, it only destroy B. Another 'lttng destroy' only gave error.
What should I do to destroy A?

Comment: ahhh… found it… `# lttng destroy A`

Comment: As you found, `lttng destroy` destroys your current session (the one found in ~/.lttngrc). As an alternative, you could have set the current session with `lttng set-session A`, followed with a `lttng destroy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to destroy all sessions:

> lttng destroy --all

Or as you found out, use the session name like this:

> lttng destroy $SESSION_NAME

For more details, look up the [`LTTNG-DESTROY(1)`](http://lttng.org/man/1/lttng-destroy/) man page.